# fstream and qfile don't create file when .app is executed on mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, fstream

I am currently developing a Qt application for MacOs and Windows. In this application I need to write and read a file. While the deployed app works perfectly fine on Windows and Linux, on Mac it won't. Currently there are 3 different "outcomes". (Only on Mac)

1. When I run the app with Qt Creator the file is created and loaded in the same
   where the executable is located (at .app/Contents/MacOS/).
2. When I execute the .app file in the deployment folder open() fails
3. When I execute the exec (at .app/Contents/MacOS/) the file is created and loaded in my home directory

There is no error message or anything, it just does nothing in case 2.
I am testing on Mac with Qt-Creator 4.5 and Qt 5.10.0 on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.2

I include fstream
Export:

```
std::ofstream csvExport;
csvExport.open("save.csv", std::ofstream::out);
```

Import

```
std::ifstream csvImport;
csvImport.open("save.csv", std::ifstream::in);
```

I observed the same behaviour, when using QFile

Comment: And you believe that the process's current directory, where this process would create the output file, is exactly what? And you checked that the `open()` call succeeded and didn't fail, exactly how?

Comment: I added a check in the code and open() fails (only) in case 2.

Comment: Now, add the code that shows you the process's current directory, and you will be able to figure out the answer all by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you have to write or read a file, Why don't you create this file in some meaningful place, e.g. inside Documents\YourAppName directory?

Rather than depending on OS and Qt implementation provide a valid path with known behavior.

You can use `QStandardPaths`Qt class to find the my documents directory.
So your directory can be `QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation`

```
QDir pathToWrite( QStandardPaths::displayName(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation) + "YourAppName" );
```

This will give you a defined behavior all the time.

Comment: It's not merely that one "can use" `QStandardPath`: it's a requirement to use it to provide portable behavior on all platforms.

Comment: @KubaOber: Indeed!

Comment: So the problem on Mac was that I needed the full path. `QStandardPaths::displayName(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation)` was not enough. In order to make it work i needed to construct the path like this:
`QDir pathToWrite(QDir::homePath()+ "/" + QStandardPaths::displayName(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation) + "/MyFolder");`
This works on Linux, Windows and MacOs

Comment: For appending the native type separator better use this:
'QDir::separator()'
It returns the native directory separator: "/" under Unix and "\" under Windows.

Better not prefix a hard-coded directory separator with your app name.